# I want to download all data from my app, but always failed

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to download all data from my gae-java app. I executed following command:

```
appcfg.py download_data --application=jeideant --url=http://jeideant.appspot.com/remote_api --filename=tickets
```

My run env is windows command line , the console show error:

```
[INFO     2013-08-07 12:33:33,898 bulkloader.py] Logging to bulkloader-log-20130807.123333
[INFO     2013-08-07 12:33:33,898 bulkloader.py] Throttling transfers:
[INFO     2013-08-07 12:33:33,898 bulkloader.py] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO     2013-08-07 12:33:33,898 bulkloader.py] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO     2013-08-07 12:33:33,898 bulkloader.py] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO     2013-08-07 12:33:33,898 bulkloader.py] Batch Size: 10
[INFO     2013-08-07 12:33:33,898 bulkloader.py] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20130807.123333.sql3
[INFO     2013-08-07 12:33:34,273 bulkloader.py] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20130807.123333.sql3
[DEBUG    2013-08-07 12:33:34,539 adaptive_thread_pool.py] [WorkerThread-0] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG    2013-08-07 12:33:34,539 adaptive_thread_pool.py] [WorkerThread-1] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG    2013-08-07 12:33:34,539 adaptive_thread_pool.py] [WorkerThread-2] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG    2013-08-07 12:33:34,539 adaptive_thread_pool.py] [WorkerThread-3] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG    2013-08-07 12:33:34,539 adaptive_thread_pool.py] [WorkerThread-4] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG    2013-08-07 12:33:34,539 adaptive_thread_pool.py] [WorkerThread-5] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG    2013-08-07 12:33:34,555 adaptive_thread_pool.py] [WorkerThread-6] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG    2013-08-07 12:33:34,555 adaptive_thread_pool.py] [WorkerThread-7] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG    2013-08-07 12:33:34,555 adaptive_thread_pool.py] [WorkerThread-8] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG    2013-08-07 12:33:34,555 adaptive_thread_pool.py] [WorkerThread-9] WorkerThread: started
[DEBUG    2013-08-07 12:33:34,555 bulkloader.py] Configuring remote_api. url_path = /remote_api, servername = jeideant.appspot.com
[DEBUG    2013-08-07 12:33:34,555 bulkloader.py] Bulkloader using app_id: jeideant
[INFO     2013-08-07 12:33:34,555 bulkloader.py] Connecting to jeideant.appspot.com/remote_api
[ERROR    2013-08-07 12:33:34,571 bulkloader.py] Exception during authentication
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkloader.py", line 3456, in Run
    self.request_manager.Authenticate()
  File "D:\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkloader.py", line 1343, in Authenticate
    remote_api_stub.MaybeInvokeAuthentication()
  File "D:\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 740, in MaybeInvokeAuthentication
    datastore_stub._server.Send(datastore_stub._path, payload=None)
  File "D:\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "D:\google\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "D:\google\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "D:\google\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "D:\google\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "D:\google\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1187, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "D:\google\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "D:\google\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "D:\google\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 373, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
BadStatusLine: ''
[ERROR    2013-08-07 12:33:34,571 bulkloader.py] Authentication Failed: Incorrect credentials or unsupported authentication type (e.g. OpenId).
```

I do try several ways, but still get this error. 
Please tell me How to deal with it? Thanks.

Comment: The google-appengine-sdk is v1.7.5 for java

Comment: In application settings , the Authentication Type is Google Accounts API, I never modify it. Is it right?

Comment: My web.xml config following: 
`<servlet> <servlet-name>remoteapi</servlet-name> <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class> </servlet> <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>remoteapi</servlet-name> <url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping> `